# Materialize scrollspy is changing the URL and refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, materialize

Materialize scrollspy (https://materializecss.com/scrollspy.html) is changing the URL and refreshing the page.

I have used the same code mentioned in the Materialize document in my Vue.js project for scrolling to particular position, but the page is getting refreshed with changing the URL by appending the selected div's Id at the end of the URL, instead of scroll.

In Template

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m9 l10">
        <div id="introduction" class="section scrollspy">
          <p>Content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="structure" class="section scrollspy">
          <p>Content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="initialization" class="section scrollspy">
          <p>Content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col hide-on-small-only m3 l2">
        <ul class="section table-of-contents">
          <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
          <li><a href="#structure">Structure</a></li>
          <li><a href="#initialization">Intialization</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Mounted:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.scrollspy').scrollSpy();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For using `ScrollSpy` of `materializecss`, first I added it in main.js file:

```js
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js'
```

Then in the component that I want to use `ScrollSpy`, I have this code:

> ScrollSpy.vue:

```html
<template>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m9 l10">
      <div id="introduction" class="section scrollspy">
        <p class="heightLong">Accusamus aliquam amet aperiam, aspernatur, atque commodi consequuntur dignissimos doloremque ea eaque earum error est fuga inventore iste mollitia nobis obcaecati, odit perspiciatis quam quibusdam recusandae repellat saepe sapiente sint! Adipisci alias aliquam aliquid dignissimos dolorum enim excepturi illo minima, pariatur perferendis repellendus suscipit totam veniam. Aperiam asperiores atque consequatur deleniti eum ex excepturi facilis mollitia pariatur, quisquam repudiandae saepe, similique ullam ut vitae voluptate voluptates. Aspernatur cumque distinctio ducimus enim et, facilis ipsa ipsum maxime neque odio omnis, recusandae repellat sapiente sunt totam unde, veritatis? Beatae distinctio ducimus ea eius est ex, fuga illum incidunt iste labore nam nihil porro provident tempore unde voluptate voluptatum. Aliquid beatae, consequuntur ea et neque nesciunt quis similique suscipit veniam voluptatum! Aliquam, aliquid cum esse fugiat ipsa perferendis placeat possimus quae unde velit! A asperiores at aut consequatur corporis delectus deleniti dignissimos dolor doloribus dolorum ducimus enim excepturi illum ipsum iste iusto libero minima, minus natus necessitatibus neque nihil odio officiis omnis pariatur perferendis quae quas, repellendus rerum saepe sed sunt tempora temporibus ullam veritatis voluptate voluptates? Aliquam amet dignissimos dolorem ea eaque enim esse est eum fugit hic illo inventore labore, laboriosam molestiae natus necessitatibus nisi odit officia optio, quae quam ratione, rem repellendus sequi tempora ullam unde! Eum eveniet hic praesentium voluptatibus! Alias, aliquam consequatur deleniti dicta exercitationem labore, laudantium magnam omnis optio perferendis possimus praesentium quidem, quos suscipit veritatis vitae voluptate voluptatum! Adipisci aliquam at atque aut dolor eaque eveniet explicabo fugit id in iste libero magni molestias nihil officia quas quibusdam, suscipit tenetur totam ut velit veniam veritatis, voluptatum. A aliquam animi asperiores atque blanditiis consectetur deleniti dolorum est ex id illum impedit incidunt iste libero maiores maxime mollitia neque nihil nisi nobis odio odit omnis perferendis possimus praesentium quae rerum, tempora ut, veritatis vero. Animi dolore est ex fuga laborum nobis suscipit! Ab ad animi asperiores autem blanditiis consequatur delectus enim ex exercitationem facere illum incidunt inventore modi molestiae necessitatibus nihil optio possimus quas quia, recusandae repellat repellendus similique soluta tempore vitae. Commodi labore saepe sequi soluta. Adipisci beatae consequatur, distinctio eos id illum ipsa iste nesciunt, nostrum perspiciatis quas quibusdam quod recusandae</p>
      </div>

      <div id="structure" class="section scrollspy">
        <p class="heightLong">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque ipsum laboriosam necessitatibus! Atque ducimus earum eligendi nulla numquam, voluptates voluptatibus. A ab animi asperiores culpa debitis deserunt dolore, dolorem doloremque earum esse explicabo fugiat hic impedit iste labore minus molestias neque nobis porro quasi, quia quis, quod repellendus vel velit? Ab architecto, aspernatur atque dolores eligendi ex fuga illo in incidunt laboriosam magnam molestiae nam neque nostrum quidem vel velit, vero voluptatibus. Corporis dolor eaque et inventore, ullam voluptatibus? Architecto atque dolor error in, nesciunt numquam quisquam quo ratione reiciendis voluptatem. Accusamus animi architecto at aut beatae corporis culpa distinctio doloremque earum eum exercitationem expedita in ipsam molestiae molestias necessitatibus, nemo neque nobis optio placeat porro quaerat ullam ut! Ab aliquid architecto asperiores delectus deleniti dolor dolore doloremque esse est expedita fugiat fugit itaque minima minus natus nemo neque perferendis possimus quibusdam recusandae reiciendis, sequi sunt suscipit totam vero vitae?</p>
      </div>

      <div id="initialization" class="section scrollspy">
        <p class="heightLong">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, assumenda deserunt dicta expedita hic ipsam laudantium libero odit praesentium provident quaerat repudiandae, rerum sapiente sequi sint ullam vero? Autem commodi, consequatur corporis cupiditate doloribus earum est incidunt iste iure minus pariatur porro rem tempore! Aspernatur autem, dignissimos dolorum ducimus necessitatibus nulla pariatur temporibus velit. Hic modi repellendus reprehenderit tempore voluptate? Assumenda atque dignissimos distinctio dolor doloremque et fuga molestiae totam vitae! Ad amet blanditiis consequuntur culpa deserunt doloremque dolores eaque eligendi enim eos explicabo fuga hic id in ipsum iusto labore libero magnam maxime minima minus molestias natus nisi non omnis porro, possimus praesentium, saepe sit soluta tempora totam voluptas voluptatum. Atque autem dolores vitae. Blanditiis commodi corporis dicta eligendi nulla ratione tempore, totam velit? A alias blanditiis, commodi consectetur cum cumque cupiditate delectus dolor dolorum error ex excepturi harum impedit iure magnam maiores modi molestias neque nisi odio, placeat provident qui recusandae rerum sit sunt temporibus tenetur vel vero, vitae. Aliquam animi aperiam, culpa cupiditate dicta distinctio eos et excepturi exercitationem explicabo harum hic impedit labore libero magnam, maiores minus molestiae mollitia nam necessitatibus nostrum officia quia repudiandae sunt suscipit temporibus unde veritatis vero voluptatibus voluptatum. Atque delectus distinctio eum, incidunt, itaque maxime nesciunt nisi quasi quis ratione repellat sunt vero voluptatum? Aliquid dolor ipsa labore nam nulla omnis pariatur saepe. Amet culpa explicabo facilis id incidunt ipsa ipsam labore maxime modi nam necessitatibus nostrum officia perspiciatis, quasi totam unde voluptates? Accusantium atque blanditiis, corporis eaque, est fugit inventore molestias omnis possimus quas quis quod sapiente tenetur, vel voluptas?</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col hide-on-small-only m3 l2">
      <ul class="section table-of-contents">
        <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#structure">Structure</a></li>
        <li><a href="#initialization">Intialization</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import M from 'materialize-css';
export default {
  name: "ScrollSpy",
  mounted() {
      let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollspy');
      M.ScrollSpy.init(elems);
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.heightLong {
  min-height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

</style>
```

I added some extra text and a CSS class for better view of "scrollspy" functionality. It works fine for me and does not change the `url` or refreshing the page.